# automatically generate header

Tags: java, eclipse

I wonder if you could automatically generate header header class functions automatically for a given package (make a batch processing) ..?
Thank you.

Comment: "automatically generate header header class functions"? What does that mean? Could you post an example of what you'd like to get generated?

Comment: Based on which data? You have to be a little more precise in order to receive satisfying answers.

Comment: i have some classes i want generate the comment and generate the header for this classes

Comment: What headers are you refering to? Are you confusing this with c? You don't need any seperate header-files in Java. If you already have the classes, you also should have the header, i.e. `public class ClassName() {`

Comment: Maybe You think about JavaDoc? You should really show us an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, place the cursor over the name of the class and press Ctrl-Shift-J.  You can customize the comment in Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Code Templates.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood well what you're asking:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates
```

There you could configure what goes at the top of the class each time you create one for instance.

Edit after op comment clarifying the question: this is not valid if you already have a class, this come into play if you have to create it.